# How to install AppCompat 21 in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat

How do I install AppCompat 21 in Eclipse? I downloaded these libs and added them to libs folder, but when I start compiling an app, I get errors.

Comment: What errors you see ? If you are trying to add appcompact.aar then eclipse will not support it.

Comment: The exclamation point next to the folder of the project.

Comment: libs folder?? appcompat is not (only) a jar.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the jar files to your own project folder libs: follow the instructions at [this link](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#), under subtitle "**Adding libraries with resources**".